# NP-hardness of an Integer Program

Tags: computational-complexity

Could someone please explain if it has been proven that the following problem is NP-hard $$\mathrm{maximize}\sum x_i$$ $$A\mathbf x\leq1$$

$$x_i\in\{0,1\}\forall i$$ where $\mathbf x = (x_1,\dots,x_N)^T$, $A$ is a constant matrix and $x_i$ are binary variables.

Answer (score 5):

looks like [set packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing#Integer_linear_program_formulation)
${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$